# Compile Error for Arduino Sketch

Tags: code-review

I am attempting to increase the volume of a Max9744 20 watt amplifier from Adafruit using an Arduino sketch. I am just a very beginner and working with my grandson, this may be more than I am capable of doing.

Our project is to have music play when a sensor determines a door is opened.

I wonder if someone can help with this compile error.  I stripped the code of any code not related to issue - basically the sensor code.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

exit status 1
'VS1053_CONTROL_SPI_SETTING' was not declared in this scope

Here is the code

```
#include <SPI.h>[code][/code]
#include <Adafruit_VS1053.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <Wire.h> // Amp Code

#define BREAKOUT_RESET 9 // VS1053 reset pin (output)
#define BREAKOUT_CS 10 // VS1053 chip select pin (output)
#define BREAKOUT_DCS 8 // VS1053 Data/command select pin (output)
// These are the pins used for the music maker shield
#define SHIELD_RESET -1 // VS1053 reset pin (unused!)
#define SHIELD_CS 7 // VS1053 chip select pin (output)
#define SHIELD_DCS 6 // VS1053 Data/command select pin (output)

// These are common pins between breakout and shield
#define CARDCS 4 // Card chip select pin
// DREQ should be an Int pin, see http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/attachInterrupt
#define DREQ 3 // VS1053 Data request, ideally an Interrupt pin

#define MAX9744_I2CADDR 0x4B

int8_t thevol = 63; // I want Max Volume Always


Adafruit_VS1053_FilePlayer musicPlayer =
Adafruit_VS1053_FilePlayer(SHIELD_RESET, SHIELD_CS, SHIELD_DCS, DREQ, CARDCS);

void setup() {
SD.begin(CARDCS);

Wire.begin();
if (! setvolume(thevol)) {
Serial.println("Failed to set volume, MAX9744 not found!");
while (1);
}
}

boolean setvolume(int8_t v) {
// cant be higher than 63 or lower than 0
if (v > 63) v = 63;
if (v < 0) v = 0;

Serial.print("Setting volume to ");
Serial.println(v);
Wire.beginTransmission(MAX9744_I2CADDR);
Wire.write(v);
if (Wire.endTransmission() == 0)
return true;
else
return false;
}
void Adafruit_VS1053::setVolume(uint8_t left, uint8_t right) {
uint16_t v;
v = left;
v <<= 8;
v |= right;

noInterrupts(); //cli();
sciWrite(VS1053_REG_VOLUME, v);
interrupts(); //sei();
}

void Adafruit_VS1053::sciWrite(uint8_t addr, uint16_t data) {
#ifdef SPI_HAS_TRANSACTION
if (useHardwareSPI) SPI.beginTransaction(VS1053_CONTROL_SPI_SETTING);
#endif
digitalWrite(_cs, LOW);
spiwrite(VS1053_SCI_WRITE);
spiwrite(addr);
spiwrite(data >> 8);
spiwrite(data & 0xFF);
digitalWrite(_cs, HIGH);
#ifdef SPI_HAS_TRANSACTION
if (useHardwareSPI) SPI.endTransaction();
#endif
}
void loop() {


while (counter < 3) {
musicPlayer.begin();
Serial.println(F("Playing track 001"));
musicPlayer.playFullFile("track001.mp3");
delay (100);
}

delay(1000);

musicPlayer.stopped();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The functions `Adafruit_VS1053::sciWrite` and `Adafruit_VS1053::setVolume` are functions from the library. They are in the [Adafruit_VS1053.cpp file](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_VS1053_Library/blob/master/Adafruit_VS1053.cpp).

You should not copy those functions to your own sketch.

The library has a few examples. Try to stay close to those examples.